# Getting a value from a relationship within a relationship in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationship

So I have a `approved_quote` relationship on my `jobs` Model.

```
public function approved_quote()
{
    return $this->hasOne(JobQuote::class, 'job_id')->whereNotNull('approved_at');
}
```

I want to pull back the products that have been quoted. I have tried a couple of methods however both have unexpected results.

**Attempt 1**

```
public function quoted_job_products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(JobProduct::class, 'job_id')->where('job_quote_id', $this->approved_quote()->first()->id ?? 0);
}
```

However `$this->approved_quote->get();` pulls back 14 records that are not really relevant (or right) and so `->first()` just pulls back the first of that which is wrong.

**Attempt 2**

```
public function quoted_job_products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(JobProduct::class, 'job_id')->where('job_quote_id', $this->approved_quote->id ?? 0);
}
```

`$this->approved_quote` returns null and so it does not work.

Any suggestions as to how this can be achieved? (Preferably without having a `approved_quote_id` on `jobs` however I will if I need to).

Comment: Wardie can you share with us the relationship between jobs, quotes, and products, please?

Comment: Jobs have many quotes. Jobs have one accepted quote (Quote with accepted_at). Quotes have products.

Comment: can you share the models relationship, in that way I can help you, please?

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting up that query in smaller pieces? This is not a finished solution but might be helpful. Not sure I got the relationships right.

#### Models

- Job
- JobProduct
- JobQuote

#### Relationships

- Job HasOne JobProduct
- Job HasMany JobQuote
- JobQuote belongsTo JobProduct

#### Solution

```
class Job extends Model {
    public function jobQuotes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(JobQuote::class);
    }

    public function approvedJobQuote()
    {
        return $this->jobQuotes()->whereNotNull('approved_at')->first()
    }

    public function approvedJobProduct()
    {
        return $this->approvedJobQuote()->jobProduct()
    }
}
```

And

```
class JobQuote extends Model {
    public function jobProduct()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(JobProduct::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->approvedJobQuote()->jobProduct()` this is wrong. You can't call realtionship on `query builder` instance.

Comment: Its not calling it on the query builder,its calling it on a JobQuote instance returned by first() in prevous step